# How to search for a pattern in a txt file and print the result of a second pattern matching on the files matching the first pattern?

Tags: bash, grep, find

Does anyone know how in bash do i make a search for a pattern A in a directory containing txt files and sub-directories (which i have to search as well), and then on the files that match pattern A, print the result of matching pattern B?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your grep calls using pipes `|`. Like this:

```
grep 'Error' file.txt | grep 'Database'
```

This fictional example will give you all error messages from within a file that are database related.

Comment: 1) your example does not search in `sub-directories `, 2) your example does not search `on the files that match pattern A`. For this you can use xargs, which takes argument from previous command's output and feed to next command. So `grep -l` will give you file names, those you can feed via xargs to next grep.

Comment: Confirmed. But the question is hard to understand. Do you also know what this stands for: `and then on the files that match pattern A, print the result of matching pattern B?` ?

Comment: i think he has some directory structure where at random level any file might contain 2 patterns, he wants to find those files. so my approach will be `grep -rl pattern1 *|xargs grep pattern2 ` or something like that. true to your words :) question is not very clear

Comment: Let us wait until the opener will eventually provide more information

Comment: Yes, I wanted something like abasu is saying. The xargs does the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
find <BASEDIR>/ -name "*PATTERN_A*" | xargs grep PATTERN_B
```

I believe this will achieve what you're looking for :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I was searching for. Thank you